how to use AsyncIOScheduler in Django?
I am developing an API using Django Rest Framework that periodically calls an asynchronous method through AsyncIOScheduler (a component of APScheduler), making it run every few seconds. However, it is not working as expected, and nothing is printed to the console. Below is my code.
Scheduler definition:
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start_scheduler():
    if not scheduler.running:
        scheduler.start()
        logging.info('scheduler started')

Code to start the scheduler:
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        from .scheduler import start_scheduler
        start_scheduler()

API endpoint definition:
class Boo():

    async def test():
        print("testFoo")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("testFoo done")
        
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.insideObjs = [Boo() for _ in range(10)]

    async def run(self):
        tasks = [boo.test() for boo in self.insideObjs]

        logging.info(f'waiting for jobs done')
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        logging.info(f'all jobs done')

class FooViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'], url_path='start')
    def start(self, request):
        foo = Foo()
        scheduler.add_job(foo.run, 'interval', seconds=3,
                          id="123", replace_existing=True)

In my expection, 'testFoo' and 'testFoo done' should get printed to the console every 3 seconds, but this does not happen. I tried to change my ready() function of ApiConfig class from:
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        from .scheduler import start_scheduler
        start_scheduler()

to
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        from .scheduler import start_scheduler
        start_scheduler()

        try:
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            pass

With this change, however, the Django server is pending forever, failing to receive any request.
I also tried to add the event loop code to manage.py:
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'foo.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

With this change, line asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever() will never execute.
How can I make the 10 Boo objects in Foo run concurrently every 3 seconds?
